# clearDB database on heroku closing connection after 1 min of inactivity

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I have deployed nodejs app on heroku using clearDB database. But it happenes that if connection is left inactive for 1 min, the server closes the connection and the app crashes. Below are my logs:

> 2019-07-02T06:21:42.052527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971546+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:183
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971591+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971598+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971601+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
>
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971603+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket. (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
>
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971605+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket. (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
>
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971607+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971610+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971612+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971614+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11
> 2019-07-02T06:22:39.971615+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>
> 2019-07-02T06:22:40.059465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
>
> 2019-07-02T06:22:40.059465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
> 2019-07-02T06:22:40.036310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error for a very long time.
I replaced

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    // my configuration 
})
```

with

```
var conn = mysql.createPool({
    // my configuration
})
```

And removed the code `var conn = connection.connect()`.
It worked like a charm!